# Vector Spaces & Matrices

Tags: vector-spaces

The vectors $\mathbf a_1, \mathbf a_2, \mathbf a_3, \mathbf b_1, \mathbf b_2, \mathbf b_3 $ are given by

$$ \mathbf a_1 = (3, 2, 1, 0) , \; \mathbf a_2 = (1, 1, 0, 0),\; \mathbf a_3 = (0, 0, 1, 0), $$ 
$$ \mathbf b_1 = (3, 2, 0, 2), \; \mathbf b_2 = (2, 2, 0, 1), \; \mathbf b_3 = (1, 1, 0, 1) $$

The subspace of $\mathbb R^4 $ spanned by $ \mathbf {a_1, a_2, a_3} $ is denoted by $\mathrm V_1 $, and the subspace of $ \mathbb R^4 $ spanned by $ \mathbf {b_1, b_2, b_3} $ is denoted by $\mathrm V_2 $. Show that $ \mathrm V_1 $ and $ \mathrm V_2 $ each have dimension 3.

The set of vectors which belong to both $ \mathrm V_1 $ and $ \mathrm V_2 $ is denoted by $ \mathrm V_3 $. Find the basis for $ \mathrm V_3 $.

The set of vectors which consists of the zero vector and all vectors which belong to only one of $ \mathrm V_1 $ and $ \mathrm V_2 $ is denoted by $ \mathrm W $.

(i) Write down two linearly independent vectors which belong to $ \mathrm W $.
(ii) Show that $ \mathrm W $ is not a linear space.

I did the first part already 'Show that $ \mathrm V_1 $ and $ \mathrm V_2 $ each have dimension 3.'
But I have no idea how to do continue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Dimension of $V_1$ intersection $V_2$ will be 2.Basis for $V_3$ is $$ \mathbf  (3, 2, 0, 0) , \; \mathbf  (1, 1, 0, 0)$$
Note that union of two subspace is a subspace if and only if one is contained in another.As none of them contained in one another that is why union W is not a linear space.

Comment: How did you get the basis for V3?

Comment: Don't worry about Basis element...Can you see that Dimension of $V_3$ is 2.Thik it Geometrically.Then take any two linearly independent element of $R^4$.That will serve as a basis.